# Using ADSI Edit on WIN-7

Tags: windows-7, rsa, adsi

I am not able to find out the ADSI EDIT on WIN-7, any help in this regard.

Any installing instruction !

PS. Install the ADSI Edit, error on launch:"MMC could not create the snap-in"

Is RSAT still available for Win7?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

RSAT for Win 7 SP 1 (includes ADSIEdit)

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7887

Comment: The important part of this document is: You have to use the Control Panel -> Progams and Features -> Turn Windows Features on and off to actually enable the features of the RSAT that your desire.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the correct version? There are three different versions:

One for XP/2003, the second for 2008 [R2] and the third for Vista and Windows 7:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=116179

Comment: Yes, Already double checked. Installed the right Version for WIN-7